# Bedeutung von "Nachmachen"

Tags: difference

Bitte, was für ein Unterschied ist zwischen "verfälschte" und "nachgemachte" Banknote? Der einzige Text, der "verfälscht oder nachmacht" direkt unterscheidet, scheint mir der altbekannte Text auf deutschen Mark-Banknoten zu sein. Aber nirgends finde ich eine Erklärung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Nachgemacht" wäre synonym zu "gefälscht".  Eine "verfälschte" Banknote wäre hingegen authentisch aber verändert.  Eine Verfälschung wäre etwa eine Änderung des abgedruckten Betrages (oder entsprechende Änderungen, die geeignet sind, einen Automaten, der Banknoten annimmt, über den Wert eines Geldscheins zu täuschen), eine Änderung der Seriennummer (um die Herkunft zu verbergen), eine Auftrennung von Vor- und Rückseite und Nutzung mit oder ohne Ersatz der fehlenden Seite.

Comment: '"Nachgemacht" wäre synonym zu "gefälscht".' - aber nur in dem Kontext. Wenn man einen Schlüssel nachmachen lässt, dann ist der entstehende neue Schlüssel eine Kopie, aber keineswegs eine Fälschung.

Answer (score 1):

Hast Du eventuell *ge*fälscht und *ver*fälscht verwechselt?

Wer etwas **nachmacht** mit dem Ziel, es als Original auszugeben, fälscht dieses Etwas. Das Partizip dazu lautet ***ge***fälscht. Im Beispiel der Banknoten beinhaltet das, ein Stück geeignetes Papier so zu bedrucken, dass es wie ein echter Geldschein aussieht.

Wird etwas ***ver*fälscht**, wird das Original so verändert, dass das Ergebnis als etwas anderes erscheint - verfälschen kann man Töne, Messergebnisse, ..., aber eben auch Banknoten. Ein etwas vereinfachtes Beispiel wäre durch das Hinzufügen zweier Nullen aus einem echten 5€-Schein einen (scheinbaren) 500€-Schein zu machen.